# Getting Error on updating Kali Linux 403 Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]

Tags: kali-linux

I have tried to update my Kali Linux recently and this is what happening

```
┌─[root@PiratePRO]─[/]
 #apt-get update

Hit:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/14.04/prod trusty InRelease                                                        
Err:2 http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease                                                                         
  403  Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]
Hit:3 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease
Reading package lists... Done              
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]
E: The repository 'http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Packages (non-free/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target Translations (non-free/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (non-free/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (non-free/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list:3
```

my source list are

```
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: No, that is clearly not your source list.

Comment: ya i have recently remove the old one with the list availabe from kali org ....befor changing too i was getting same error

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the correct repository, as [documented on the Kali web site](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: but its soo slow ..like 32KBps ..

Comment: @princejacob Maybe you should use another Linux that provide package repositories at a higher bandwidth?