# "Error: Forbidden" when I try to apt-get update

Tags: kali-linux

```
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental InRelease                                                          
Err:2 http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease                                                                 
  403  Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]
Hit:3 http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease                                                                  
Hit:4 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease           
Hit:5 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]
E: The repository 'http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: and my source list is:::deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

Comment: what is the solution

Answer (score 2):

You have an entry in your repositories which references `repo.kali.org`, which is no longer usable (see [Getting Error on updating Kali Linux 403 Forbidden [IP: 144.217.77.182 80]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/427640/86440)). You need to find that entry and remove it; it could be in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

See also [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/399626/86440) for some useful information regarding Kali Linux.

Comment: amazing....that worked...thank you very much sir